# Get request URL when using ClientBase

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am using ClientBase in a proxy to call a REST over WCF service of mine using the service interface:

```
public class CommunicationServiceProxy : ClientBase<ICommunicationService>, ICommunicationService
```

I also add before each call a authorization header so my service will accept the request, like this:

```
private OperationContextScope AddHeader(OperationContextScope scope)

        {
            if (WebOperationContext.Current == null) return null;

            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", Header);

            return scope;
        }
```

Everything is working fine, but now, because of security resons, I need to generate a signature of the request URL(eg. `http://myservice/contact/getstatus?id=1`), the problem is how to get this URL when using a proxy class like the one above, seens like WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest is missing this information.

Anyone have managed to get this? What are my options here?

Thanks

Comment: You should have either an Endpoint or ChannelFactory passed in on the constructor, right? Either of those will have the target URL.

Comment: Thank you Chris, but what I am after is not the endpoint URL, this would be like eg. 'http ://myservice', I am after the method URL as defined in REST template, eg. 'http: //myservice/contact/getstatus?id=1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to use WCF extensions, more specificly IClientMessageInspector, there I have all the information I need to generate the signature.